# Ubuntu 22.04 Can't Play Disney+ Videos After Update

Tags: drm

Disney+ videos refuse to play in either Firefox or Chrome. I get no error codes.

Comment: After update of what, specifically?

Answer (score 21):

Solution for Firefox browser:

1. Enter `about:config` in the URL input field and accept the risk.
2. Search for `general.useragent.override`.
3. Select *String* and click <kbd>+</kbd>.
4. In the input field enter:

   ```
   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:106.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/106.0
   ```
5. Accept the changes and refresh the page and the video will load.
6. Be sure not to forget to clear your browser's cache.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/yfjaa1/comment/iu6916h/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: This solution works! You're a life saver! Thanks.

Comment: Genius, worked for me, thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 5):

Solution for Chrome/Chromium:

- Open Dev Tools (Ctrl+Shift+I)
- Open Network Conditions (Ctrl+Shift+P) and search for "Show network conditions"

In the user agent section uncheck "Use browser default" and add the custom string from Pat's answer:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:106.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/106.0
```

Refresh the page and it should work.

Comment: Thank you! Works great!